# Manifest attribute for java jar

Tags: java, manifest.mf

With all the help from you i was able to finish my first project in java. Now i want to create a jar and run the application (Java project - it is a plain console application which is having another project(console application) as a dependence) from jar.

I created a jar with eclipse by right click - export - created a jar. When i try to run this jar from my cmd, I have an error (below is the error I am geting)

```
no main manifest attribute, in AAA.jar
```

I Googled the error - most of them subjected to create the Manifest file. I created a manifest file like below in the project equal to src level

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.Pacakename.mainclass
Class-Path: log4j-1.2.16.jar db2jcc.jar db2jcc_license_cu.jar
```

Then J tried run the jar again but this time it says no main method where i have a main method in the class

Please some one please explain a clear step's for creating the Manifest(it really help's me if you show me the folder structure of the place where we have Manifest file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets assume you have following directory structure:

```
MyJavaProject
   |-src 
      |- com
          |- example
               |- Main.java
```

To compile such project in cmd line, (no external dependencies) you need to invoke commands

```
$ cd MyJavaProject
$ mkdir bin         //to separate *.class file from source files
$ javac -d bin src\com\example\Main.java
```

This will create `Main.class` file in `bin` directory. To pack it to *.jar file, you can:
1) create jar with binary files and specify Main class in cmd
2) create Manifes and embbed it to jar (I will focus on this one)

You should create `META-INF` directory under `src` and inside it create `MANIFEST.mf` file

Your manifest should look like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: <Your info>
Main-Class: com.example.Main
```

**Remember to add empty line at end on Manifest!!**

In this case, you specify `Manifest-Version` attribute, `Created-By` attribute, and fully qualified name of main class to run in `Main-Class` attribute

To create Jar with this Manifest file and you binary file, invoke commands

```
$ cd bin
$ jar cfm MyJavaProject.jar ..\src\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF .
```

this will create new jar called `MyJavaProject.jar` and use your manifest

If you project depends on external classas or jar, add them to your classpath when compiling (`-cp` option) and add another line in `Manifest`

```
ClassPath: path/to/dependent/jars/jar.jar
```

Recompile it and create new jar and enjoy your Java quest :)

For more info on Manifest please see: [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)

PS: Working with jars,amnifest from cmd line might seem ugly, but it can teach you some ava-like concepts. If you want to skip it, please consider using [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)

Comment: That you so much for explaining me so clearly, while reading your response i understand few topics i am going to implement the above with my cmd.

Comment: It worked -:), i could able to generate the jar and run it, Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **maven** I can recommend you to use the [*shade plugin*](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to produce runnable jars with all dependencies (and **manifest** :-)) on-board.

Include this in your **pom.xml**:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <!-- your main class: -->
                  <mainClass>org.sonatype.haven.HavenCli</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

And then execute `mvn clean package shade:shade` to build a jar that you can run from the command line with `java -jar jarfilename.jar`.

Comment: No i am not using it, A Maven is not approved at my work place-:(, Please sugest me how to do it with out using Maven

Comment: Are you using plain eclipse? Or an IBM-ified version (RAD)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse you can use "Export" --> Runnable jar to achieve your goals.
In that case you should have a valid run configuration for your project since eclipse uses this run configuration as a kind of blueprint for the runnable jar.

In this case eclipse will build the manifest for you.

Comment: Instead of using "Export --> Runnable jar" in Eclipse, I much prefer using a Maven pom.xml to define my executable .jar build.  Obviously, this requires installing the "M2E" Maven plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: @djangofan But the maven way is more difficult to explain here. In my daily work I also use maven, ant or gradle in combination with build systems for generating the jars. Production releases should never be built on a workstation in my opinion, only on a dedicated build-system.

Comment: @mschenk74 i tried the same way you sujjested bu twhen i try run that har, Still i get the same error message No manifest attribute